# What's the total energy required to completely ionize an atom of oxygen?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics

From what I found, the formula for calculating the energy level of an atom is:
$$ E_n=-hcR_{\infty}\cdot\frac{{Z_{eff}}^{2}}{n^{2}}$$
Where,
$E_n$ = Energy Level,
$h$ = Planck Constant,
$c$ = Speed of Light,
$R$ = Rydberg Constant,
$Z$ = Effective Nuclear Charge,
$n$ = Principal Quantum Number.

By my calculations, in an atom of oxygen, where $n = 1$,
$E_n = -1.96188509×10^{-17}J$.

And, where $n = 2$,
$E_n = -1.39511829×10^{-16}J$.

So, as the atom of oxygen have $8$ electrons, is it right to assume that it will require:

$$ 6×-1.96188509×10^{-17} J + 2 ×-1.39511829×10^{-16} J$$
$$= -3.9673676×10^{-16} J $$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: To first approximation, yes, that is the correct line of thinking, although I did not double check any of your numbers.

Comment: @nasu Seriously? You will tell me that you did not understand me, when I asked "What's the total energy required to completely ionize an atom of oxygen", clearer than that, impossible.

Comment: @JonathanJeffrey I thought that, as you remove electrons, it becomes more and more difficult to remove another electron, but as you said that my line of thought is right, it really gets more difficult, but at each level, and it doesn't change to electrons of the same level, right?

Comment: @ガブリエルGabriel That's why I said it was a first approximation. Most of the validity of the approximation comes from using $Z_eff$, which includes the shielding effect of electrons from lower levels $n$. Electrons at the same level $n$ still matter, but just not nearly as much; hence why the approximation works.

Comment: @JonathanJeffrey If you know, could you show me how to make a more correct result? Even if it involves calculus?